Flux.1 Dev on Linux/Ubuntu home server /w Xeons/substantial resources/accelerators, ComfyUI running on Win10 laptop. How do I arrange this feat?
I was given a cheap server recently, a Dell PowerEdge, and it might make a good platform for running FLUX.1 Dev using math-accelerators as it has 192GB RAM but it has NO GPU and no VRAM.
The server is connected to my home router.
I already have a laptop with NVidia Cuda cores but insufficient memory powerful enough to run FLUX AI on its own however it should be capable of running ComfyUI.
I want to run the ComfyUI on the Win10 laptop but use the raw grunt of the server running Ubuntu 24.04 to do the heavy lifting on Flux.1 Dev using CPU alone and later utilize any math-accelerators I have access to.
What I'd like to know is;
a) is this possible and if so how do I do this?
b) should I install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server to do for this?
The server has no virtualization/GPU capabilities but I do have access to discarded TPUs and math-accelerators.
Surely it is a simple network problem?

all Data and AI processing on server
GUI running on win10 laptop
via home network


This sounds like a larger project than Ubuntu.  Especially because you are trying to ix Windows 10 ComfyUI and a separate system with distributed computing.  You may want to ask this in a ComfyUI forum or such because getting ComfyUI and communication with secondary systems and such is going to be Painful (most distributed solutions are)

I was under the impression that networks were designed to do all this in the 1970s? Its still impossible in the 2020s?

it's not a question of the network but the systems / software in place and whether it can offload to other systems with distributed processing.

So in the 2020s we cannot just tell software that folders are 'on the network someplace' rather than local on a hard-drive closest to the nearest CPU and all that nonsense be handled seamlessly? What have network 'experts' being doing all these years? Playing tetris?

I seriously thought this would be a simple thing. I'm genuinely baffled it isn't. Server-Terminal tech has been around since the 1960s.
